# Migrate Sesame repository

Tags: semantic-web, sesame, triplestore

I want to migrate native Sesame repository to postgresql based repository. 
I have no found any read solution for this task.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be aware that the Sesame PostgreSQL store (as well as the MySQL store) are being deprecated, which means they will still be available, but no longer actively supported or maintained.

That being said, a simple way to migrate is as follows:

1. Export the data from your native repository to file, using either Sesame Binary RDF format, or TriG/TriX/N-Quads. You can do an export programmatically, or using one of several Sesame client tools, including the command console or the Workbench.
2. Set up your new PostgreSQL store
3. Load the exported datafile into your new PostgreSQL store.

For more details on each of the individual steps, have a look in the [Sesame documentation](http://www.openrdf.org/documentation.jsp).